# Did Prophet ﷺ advice to divide the day into 3 parts, one for prayer, one for family, and one for work?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I was listening to a lecture by Hamza Yusuf in which he said something along the lines of (if my memory serves me correct), that Prophet ﷺ told us to divide the day into 1/3s.

1/3 for Prayer/Worship, 1/3 for Family, sleep, etc, and 1/3 for work.

I can't find any reference to this however on the internet, does anyone have a reference? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Chapter 47
Hadith 342
Shamail Al Tirmidhi

Dr. Muhammed umar sabsub said about it, that it is very weak

Due to Jamee’ ibn umar ibn abdulrahman al-ajly